# How do I specify which Oracle client install to use?

Tags: oracle, oracleclient

I have a server with both 10g and 11g clients installed.  How do I setup the connection string to tell my ASP.NET application to use the second client which is 11g (i.e. OraClient11g_home2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**documentation**](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/faq.html):

> In `ODP.NET 10.2.0.2.20` and higher, `ODP.NET` can run more than one active `Oracle Home` concurrently without requiring any special setup by the administrator.
>
> When `ODP.NET` is installed, the `DL`L search path will be based on the following order:
>
> 1. directory of the application/executable
>
>    - directory specified by `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\<version>\DllPath`
>    - directories specified by the `PATH` environment variable
>
> Upon an `ODP.NET` installation, the `DllPath` registry value of type `REG_SZ` will be set to the `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin` directory where the corresponding dependent `DLL`s are installed.

Make sure you are using `ODP.NET` as a provider and set your `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I fid Oracle Locator Express to be a useful tool. This will let you change your ORACLE_HOME on the fly:
[Oracle Locator Express](http://www.dbmotive.com/oracle_home_selector.php)